# Clicking WPF window created on 2nd thread causes it to stop responding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

In my current project I'm creating a WPF based progress window in a second thread. See my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279572/create-a-wpf-progress-window-on-another-thread) for details on how I'm doing this.

My delegate method to open my progress window on a second thread looks like this:

```
void ShowProgressWindow()
{
    this.progressWindow = new ProgressWindow();
    progressWindow.Show();

    //Causes dispatcher to shutdown when window is closed
    progressWindow.Closed += (s, e) => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);

    //Notifies other thread the progress window is open when the dispatcher starts up
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Func<bool>(_progressWindowWaitHandle.Set));

    //Starts the dispatcher
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();


    //Forces the worker to cancel work
    workerInstance.RequestCancel();
}
```

So if the user closes the window while the process is still running, the dispatcher will shutdown, the code will continue from Dispatcher.Run() to the next line where the work will be canceled. After which the progress window thread will exit.

This works fine if the window is closed by clicking the X in the top right of the window. The window closes immediately and the work is canceled.

Yet if I click the cancel button I've added to the window the progress window does not close, and completely stops responding. My cancel button has a very simple click event handler which simply calls Close() on the window.

```
private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

If I set a breakpoint inside this method it never ends up being hit after I click the button.

The XAML for my button is pretty standard

```
<Button x:Name="cancelButton"  Content="Cancel" Grid.Row="7" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,12,12" Width="75" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="cancelButton_Click" />
```

After messing with this some more I realized that clicking *anywhere* in the window, not just the cancel button, will cause it to stop responding. When the window first opens I can drag it around the screen by grabbing the title bar, but if I click anywhere inside the window it will freeze.

Comment: Try opening it from the UI thread instead?

Comment: This is a rather atypical situation. My tools is a plug-in for another piece of software which is actually providing the thread that runs my code. My code must do the actual work on the thread provided by the software, so the progress window has to be created in a second thread.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure out this problem? What version of Revit were you trying it in? I'm running into the exact same issue on Revit 2012

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to run some code on the UI thread... I prefer this way:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate()
{
    // Open window here
});
```